# wordpress php foreach can not display pictures and hyperlinks to another page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to learning to use wordpress.

My problem is that when writing wordpress, php foreach can display the name and price, but it cannot display the picture and hyperlink to the order.php page in the foreach at the same time, because I know the following spelling is wrong, can someone please explain how to display the picture correctly And what about hyperlinks? What kind of links can you learn from the same link?
What about wordpress php links?

```html
<?php include('header.php');?>

    <h1>寶石預訂</h1>
    <h2><?php echo date('n');?>月優惠</h2>
    <div class="flex-grid">
    
    <?php
//到MySQL部份,我們將會將這些資料放到資料庫裏
$gems =
[
    [
        'gem_id'    => 1,
        'name'      => '鑽石',
        'price'     => 500,
        'image'     => '透寶.jpg',
        'remaining' => 5 
    ],
    [
        'gem_id'    => 2,
        'name'      => '紅心寶石',
        'price'     => 600,
        'image'     => '紅寶.jpg',
        'remaining' => 5 
    ],
    [
        'gem_id'    => 3,
        'name'      => '黃寶石',
        'price'     => 650,
        'image'     => '黃寶.jpg',
        'remaining' => 5 
    ],
    [
        'gem_id'    => 4,
        'name'      => '綠寶石',
        'price'     => 700,
        'image'     => '綠寶.jpg',
        'remaining' => 5 
    ],
]

?>
    
    <?php
      //顯示資料
      foreach($gems as $key  => $gem)    
      {
        echo '<div class="col">
        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/assets/picture/images/'.$gem['image'].'"/>
        <p>
        名稱: '.$gem['name'].'<br>
        價格: $'.$gem['price'].'<br>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>/order.php?gem_id='.$gem['gem_id'].'"
         class="buyBtn">預訂'.$gem['name'].'</a><br>
         </div>';
      }
    ?>
    </div>
    
<?php include('footer.php');?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You mixed PHP and html. If you use PHP, you should to begin `<?php`.
The correct loop is:

```php
    <?php
      foreach($gems as $key  => $gem)    
      {?>
        <div class="col">
        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/assets/picture/images/<?php echo $gem['image'];?>"/>
        <p>
       <?php echo '名稱: '.$gem['name'].'<br>
        價格: $'.$gem['price'].'<br>
        <a href="'. the_permalink(). '/order.php?gem_id='.$gem['gem_id'].'"
         class="buyBtn">預訂'.$gem['name'].'</a><br>
         </div>';
      }
    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the modification you taught, but after trying your modification, the pictures cannot be displayed and hyperlinks are used. I wonder if there are other modification methods?

Comment: Debug your code. You missing ; after the array.